# Thread dump in JBoss 5.1

Tags: java, jboss, java-7, suse

We want to generate thread dump in JBoss 5.1.0.  We are using SUSE Linux Enterprise Server 11 and Java 1.7.
First we got JBoss process id and executed below mentioned command.

```
jstack 16917 >> threaddump.log
```

We are getting command not found message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you confirmed the < java_home >/bin is in your path?  Jstack should be available with java 1.7.  You can also check and confirm that jstack is present under your < java_home >/bin directory.  Whatever user you are logging in with on the Unix SUSE box to try and execute jstack enter

```
> echo $PATH
```

and confirm that java/bin is appearing in the path.  If it's not present you will need to modify the user profile and add into your path configuration.

Comment: It is working fine after adding java_home in .bash_profile.  Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

JStack is available since Java 5, and bundled with JDK and not available with JRE only version.

If it is *nix , you could try the below to generate the thread dump.

> kill -3

( It only suspends the java process and continues after the thread dump is generated )